# What is necessary to toggle fullscreen in DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, toggle, fullscreen, directx-11

I've just started learning DX so I know almost nothing about it although I do know OpenGL (to certain extent). I'm follow a tutorial (http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html) and I have a working window rendering just a white background (clear).

Now - how do I actually switch from windowed mode to fullscreen and vice versa? I know there are many tutorials, some even provide a code for doing that but since I'm a newbie that's not really helpful. Why? Because every code sample is different and trying to find a pattern in all of them is apparently too difficult for me.

So I don't ask for code - instead I would like you to tell me **what things I need to release/recreate/change** to toggle correctly (and all of them). I know I need to change the display settings, I know I have to change something about the swap chain and release/recreate some buffers - but not really sure which exactly.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the DirectX samples, I know that multiple of them have full screen button that you can inspect.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SetFullScreenState on your swap chain:

```
swapChain->SetFullScreenState(true, NULL);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb174579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't really think that's enough.

Comment: Why not?  Have you tried using this method, do you encounter problems or errors?

Comment: Can you correct the typo ? It's only one letter so I can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing you have to do is release all reference to the `IDXGISwapChain`, call `ResizeBuffers`, then re-create everything.

Since Win32 throws the `WM_SIZE` message upon window initialization, it's entirely possible to:

- Clear the previous window-size-specific context
- If the swap chain already exists, resize it, otherwise create one
- Obtain the backbuffer for this window which will be the final 3D rendertarget.
- Create a view interface on the rendertarget to use on bind.
- Allocate a 2-D surface as the depth/stencil buffer and create a DepthStencil view on this surface to use on bind.
- Create a viewport descriptor of the full window size.
- Set the current viewport using the descriptor.

inside a `static` function (unless `WinMain` has an object from which to call), and call that function when the `WM_SIZE` message is triggered.

You can check out how the DirectXTK does it here:
https://directxtk.codeplex.com/